# What does "face as sharp as a pen" mean?

Tags: idioms

I am reading a text and there is a phrase which I don't know the meaning of:

> His face was as sharp as a pen.

What does it mean?

Comment: Try Googling "as sharp as a pen". Quill pens were very pointed in Shakespeare's day. Mostly, this seems to be a simile applied to noses, but chins can be quite pointed too.

Comment: There is the expression ***sharp-faced***: having very clearly defined facial features http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sharp-faced. As sharp as a pen is an unusual metaphor referring to a face...probably more context is needed.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase appears to be a reference to the controversial phrase from Shakespeare's Henry V (Act 2 Scene 3)

> for his nose was **sharp as a pen**, and a'babbled of green fields

later

> for his nose was **sharp as a pen**, and a table of green fields

[google books](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=LTMlM_mK6mYC&pg=PA257&lpg=PA257&dq=for%20his%20nose%20was%20as%20sharp%20as%20a%20pen,&source=bl&ots=uSD5abl5yE&sig=wxW18Bluztx3PTdh3szUuIFiOso&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4UVoVbCdI5KTuAT91ILYBQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=for%20his%20nose%20was%20as%20sharp%20as%20a%20pen%2C&f=false)

[lrb.co](http://www.lrb.co.uk/v29/n09/michael-dobson/for-his-nose-was-as-sharpe-as-a-pen-and-a-table-of-greene-fields)

Reading the sources I quoted, one learns that this phrase baffled editors. Some thought it a mistake and corrected it. Some tried to figure out the real meaning behind it.

From the google book "Notes and Emendations to the Text of Shakespeare's Plays"

> ...writing tables were no doubt at that period often covered with green cloth; and it is to the sharpness of a pen, in relief of a table so covered, that Mrs. Quickly likens the dying wit of the philosopher...

Of course, all of this borders on speculation, but I'd say that your writer was trying to describe a similar situation.

Sparknotes [translates this](http://nfs.sparknotes.com/henryv/page_66.html) as `gaunt`.

So you could consider this to mean a [gaunt](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gaunt) face.

Answer (score 0):

[sharp](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sharp) three first meanings :

> - **Able to cut** easily.
> - (colloquial) Intelligent.
> - Terminating in a point or edge; **not obtuse or rounded.**

Pens were sharpened with knife to be able to keep writing with them. So the face weren't **round** as their are now but with angles.

As @Josh61 suggests, **sharp-faced** is a face with angles, not round.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this definition from Collins Dictionary, I imagine the author is alluding to the person having a very defined face.

> **sharp-faced** (also **sharp-featured**) *adjective*
>
> having very clearly defined facial features

*Source: Collins Dictionary*